# when I run a python file which call another one ,how can I pass some arguments to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example ,I have two python file :

- the fist one contain some code `first_file.py`:

```py
a = 1
import second_file
```

the second file contain code `second_file.py`:

```py
print(a)
```

so,when I run first file (`first_file.py`) I got a exception because `second_file.py` don't have an variable `a`,

```py
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

What I wanner do is use the ‘a’ from fist file ,then print it by calling second file.

Comment: Try `from second_file import a`

Comment: thank you for your answer! but if the file1 is my main program,how to solve this problem without recode file2?

Comment: You will have to make changes in your `main` file to use variables from other scripts

Comment: Your logics is wrong @Xaine. You want a code ("second") to use a variable ('a') out of its scope. I refer you to read about Python namespaces, lexical scope and the import process. And if are not into those readings, just think with me: you are asking `second_file` to print something that is not defined there, nor are you "loading" it from somewhere else(!), this is not logically right (unless you're into global variables black-magic). Imagine somebody handle you `second_file.py` and ask you to debug, first and last question you'd do: "where the hell is 'a' coming from?". Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

In file2.py:

```
from file1 import *
```

Then you can use all functions and variables in file2.

Comment: thank you for your answer! but if the file1 is my main program,how to solve this problem without recode file2?

Comment: No, this causes circular import

Comment: What do you mean by main program? Can you be more specific?

Comment: yes,to simplify this problem,what I want to do is running file1 and pass some variable from file1 to file2 which I calling in file1. So,how to do this without change the code of file2.

Comment: Try this in file1: "from file2 import a, print" then you can use functions and variables in file1. When the interpreter reaches print statement, then it will fetch function declaration in file2.

Comment: thanks,I will try to recode my python file.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass this variable in second file via function paramter.

Make one function in second file and pass this `a` to this function.

like this:

```
#first file
a = 1
from second_file import some_function
some_function(a)

#second file
def some_function(a):
    print(a)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I know this solution，and it need to recode file2 .Can I pass 'a' to file2 when runing file1?